# Graphviz/Dot - how to mark all leaves in a tree with a distinctive color?

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I have a script which prints a graph as .dot file. I would like to highlight all vertices of different degree with distinctive colors. Is it possible with Graphviz?

So, I am interested in the following:

```
For each i-degree vertex use color[i].
```

and as a special case, how to mark all leaves in a tree with a distinctive color? :

```
For each 1-degree vertex use color_A.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the graphviz utility gvpr for writing graph scripts.
In particular,

gvpr -c 'N[degree==1]{color="red"}'

You can enhance this to define an array (or associative map) and look up color[$.degree]

Stephen North

Comment: For leaf nodes, you may want to specify that it has no outgoing edges `gvpr -c 'N[outdegree==0]{color="red"}'`