# How can I merge nodes in a graph?

Tags: graph, graphviz, graph-algorithm

I would like to merge nodes which are semantically identically in my application. Is there a tool or algorithm I can use to process my graph?

**Input Example:** nodes **a** and **b** should be merged.

```
digraph g {                                                                     
  a -> {b;c;d;e};                                                               
  b -> {a;c;d;e};                                                               
}
```

Image of graph using `dot`:

[image: nodes a and b should be merged]

**Output Example:** nodes **a** and **b** have been merged into a node **ab**.

```
digraph g {                                                                     
  ab -> {c;d;e};                                                                
}
```

[image]

**Rough Sketch Algorithm:**

```
# XE = a set of nodes, represent a directed edge (x,_)
# YE = a set of nodes, representing a directed edge (y,_)
# XE \ y = XE except y
# YE \ x = YE except x

For each pair of nodes x,y
  If (edges (x,y) and (y,x) exists) AND (XE \ y == YE \ x)
    create new node xy -> xedges\y
    delete nodes x and y and their edges
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I know it has been a very long time but did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool: it's called [`gvpr`](https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) which stands for *graph pattern scanning and processing language*.

From the linked pdf:

> **gvpr** is a graph stream editor inspired by **awk**. It copies input graphs to its output, possibly transforming their structure and
> attributes, creating new graphs, or printing arbitrary information.

I'm sure you can achieve what you need by creating a gvpr program.

I don't have the time to create a working solution, but you may take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7362207/63733) for an example gvpr program and additional information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function built into Graphviz, but you may be able to pre-process your graph with the aid of a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)