# Does the DOT language support variables / aliases?

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to print out a directed graph, and I keep changing various node attributes such as color and shape. Is there some way to use a variable which is defined once and used for multiple nodes? Ideally I'd like something like this:

```
digraph g { 

building_color = "red"
land_color = "green"

farm  [ fillcolor=land_color]
barn  [ fillcolor=building_color]
house  [ fillcolor=building_color]

}
```

So I can change building color once without having to go to each node. Is this possible?

Answer (score 33):

You can define **default values** in order to avoid repetition:

```
digraph g{
   node[fillcolor=red];
   barn;
   house;
   ...
   node[fillcolor=green];
   farm;
   ...

   edge[color=red];
   barn -> house;
   edge[color=green];
   barn --> farm;
   house --> farm;
}
```

*Real* variables are not supported.

---

A more complex workaround would be to use [`gvpr`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) - **graph pattern scanning and processing language**.

`gvpr` reads and outputs graph and allows to add and modify graphs, nodes and attributes.

You could for example store custom information in the [`comment`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:comment) attribute and have your script act based on the content of this attribute.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6687261/63733) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7362207/63733) SO answer contain examples of `gvpr` scripts.

Comment: `barn --> farm;` is this a typo or some feature I am not aware of ? -> `barn -> farm;` ?

Answer (score 26):

The easiest solution is to use `m4` - a [generic text-to-text preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_m4).

`SampleGraph.dot.m4`:

```
digraph g { 

   define(`building_style',`style=filled, fillcolor = "red"')
   define(`land_style',`style=filled, fillcolor = "green"')

   farm  [label="Farm", land_style]
   barn  [building_style]
   house [label="House", building_style]
}
```

Run `m4 SampleGraph.dot.m4 > SampleGraph.dot`

Resulting `SampleGraph.dot` :

```
digraph g { 




   farm  [label="Farm", style=filled, fillcolor = "green"]
   barn  [style=filled, fillcolor = "red"]
   house [label="House", style=filled, fillcolor = "red"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**graphviz-py**](https://github.com/Alwinator/graphviz-py) it allows you to execute Python code inside of Graphviz diagrams.

### Example

```
digraph g {
{{
building_color = "red"
land_color = "green"
}}

node[style=filled]

farm  [ fillcolor={{= land_color }}]
barn  [ fillcolor={{= building_color }}]
house  [ fillcolor={{= building_color }}]

}
```

### Output

[image: Output]